# BreadCrumbs - ASP.NET - VS2008

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

In my old web app, asp.net 1.1 days, i had custom 'breadcrumbs' for site navigation. I want to redo my website using VS-2008. Does this have a built in breadcrumbs which can be placed on a master page? If so can anyone point me to the right direction?

This is what i envision

Master Pages has tab like navigation options and when they click on a certain naviagtion option, i will enable the SiteNavigation control and highlight the selected tab in master pages

Answer (score 3):

Use a SiteMapPath control. If the breadcrumb data is static use the Web.sitemap file to define it and you're set. If it's dynamic subclass the SiteMapProvider class to define your own logic and use a standard SiteMapPath control to display it.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a Bread Crumb type of control for .NET 2.0+, it works with the SiteMap.xml which will also allow you to add a sitemap.  It's fairly easy to use but the site has to be statically laid out, otherwise you have to create a custom sitemap provider (which isn't terribly difficult).  Take a look at [This blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221101933/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/AzamSharp/archive/2006/08/16/88197.aspx) that describes using the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is the sitemappath object, which requires that a sitemap be included in the project